# Prevent items to be 'droppable' in other (parent/child) elements

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I use knockout-sortable.js to let the user drag and drop items to give them a different order, but I'm experiencing problems when I have multiple 'drop zones' on my page. I have nested sets, all of which are sortable, but *not* interchangeable.

My code:

```
    <div class="sortable" data-bind="sortable: blueprint.pages">
          <tr><td>Blabla</td></tr>
    </div>
```

And at some other point:

```
    <div class="sortable" data-bind="sortable: selectedPage().page_sections">
          <tr><td>Another blabla</td></tr>
    </div>
```

I can now just drag and drop 'Another blabla' into 'Blabla', causing errors. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about this. The first is to pass in to knockout-sortable the connectClass as false or null (or anything that is equal to false when expressed as a boolean):

```
<div class="sortable" data-bind="sortable: { data: blueprint.pages, connectClass: false }">
    <tr><td>Blabla</td></tr>
</div>

<div class="sortable" data-bind="sortable: { data: selectedPage().page_sections, connectClass: false }">
      <tr><td>Another blabla</td></tr>
</div>
```

You can also pass, into jQuery, the containment option:

```
<div class="sortable" data-bind="sortable: { data: blueprint.pages, options: { containment: 'parent' } }">
    <tr><td>Blabla</td></tr>
</div>

<div class="sortable" data-bind="sortable: { data: selectedPage().page_sections, options: { containment: 'parent' } }">
      <tr><td>Another blabla</td></tr>
</div>
```

This, unlike the first solution, will stop the item from visually leaving the box (if that's your desire).

Comment: One other way is you can set `ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.allowDrop = false;` globally or pass `allowDrop` in the binding.  This will prevent it from being a target for anyone to drop to (you can still sort within).  It would have the same affect as `connectClass: false`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had luck with either solution. I would like to go for the containment option, but I'm not sure what I should replace 'parent' with. I tried the id and class name of the element I wanna bind it to, but I can still drag it in any other 'drop zone'. What am I missing here?

Comment: According to the documentation, you should be able to pass in a selector, e.x. "#id" or ".sortable". You can probably also pass in `this`.